# Why does pytest show wrong notification for skipped test?

Tags: pytest

I run the following test file through `pytest`:

```
import pytest
@pytest.mark.skip(reason="no way of currently testing this")
def test_1():
    pass
```

and get the following output:

```
/PROJECTS/Pytest_example/env/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/pycharm-5.0.3/helpers/pycharm/pytestrunner.py -p pytest_teamcity /PROJECTS/Pytest_example/test_example.py
Testing started at 17:57 ...
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.10, pytest-2.9.1, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1
rootdir: /PROJECTS/Pytest_example, inifile: 
collected 1 items

../../PROJECTS/Pytest_example/test_example.py s
Test ignored.

========================== 1 skipped in 0.01 seconds ===========================

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Why didn't I get the notification

```
"no way of currently testing this"?
```

How to get this notification in the output?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an output coming from something else (as you're not running pytest directly), not from pytest. You can tell pytest to show skip reasons using `-rs`:

```
$ py.test test_example.py -rs
====================== test session starts ======================
platform linux -- Python 3.5.1, pytest-2.9.1, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1
rootdir: /home/florian/tmp/so, inifile: 
plugins: mock-0.11.0
collected 1 items 

test_example.py s
==================== short test summary info ====================
SKIP [1] test_example.py:1: no way of currently testing this

=================== 1 skipped in 0.00 seconds ===================
```